# Build number or most recent commit # with AWS CodePipeline node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-codepipeline

I'd like to make the CodePipeline Build# (`CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER`) available to my node code that is being deployed. Currently there are only two steps in the pipeline: pull from bitbucket, then deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, so I don't know how this would work.

Alternatively, if I could get the most recent commit number available to my node.js code, that would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This demonstrate how to specify an artifact name that is created at build time.[example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-buildspec-artifact-naming.html)

Comment: 1. This tells me how to modify/create an artifact name. Any way my code can get access to this at build time so that it's in the code, or at least in an environment var accessible at run-time? 2. So you're saying I have to introduce a CodeBuild step, yes? I can't do it without this extra step?

Comment: My mistake that I mentioned wanting a CodePipeline env var, when it's actually in CodeBuild. Is there something similar in CodePipeline?